# Unusual way for OS to start - text shown instead of Ubuntu image

Tags: login, startup, system

Since I've made small upgrades from upgrade manager, I started getting this unusual starting process (line of codes).

[image: photo of screen with service starting messages]

After that, my OS is fully loaded, but I want to make this as need.

Comment: What is the unusual part ?

Comment: This is a part of the normal boot process. Or do you expect the [splash screen](https://static.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/muo-linux-plymouth-splash-default.png) instead?

Comment: Yeah i forgot, i want to see splash screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a unusual screen. The lines you see there are the details of boot process, and every line you see there has a meaning.

If you want your splash screen back (which you're here referring to Ubuntu Image), reinstall Plymouth.

What is Plymouth?

It's responsible for showing boot animations/splash on Ubuntu(Atleast stock).

EDIT : Before doing anything try hitting ESC or F1~F10 while you see this screen, it may take you back to the Plymouth Splash Screen.